# Need to remove previously added attachment from the list in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

I am working on a project in Angular 8 in which I need to add attachment while replying to any discussion.
My problem is in the current session when I reply to any discussion and then if I add any document it will add successfully. but when I add or reply to any discussion second time it adds the previously added document also.

The problem I am facing when I don't refresh the page when I refresh the page the previously added document removed.

I need to remove the previously added document while adding the second or third discussion.

whenever I am adding any discussion I clear the data by using this.

```
this.dataService.setFileData = null;
this.dataService.changeFileData(null);
```

below is the code that is I am using while adding any new discussion

```
let date: Date = new Date();

      let post: PostDiscussion = new PostDiscussion();

      this.loadContainerInfo();

      console.log(this.containerId + '-' + this.containerType);
      post.commentUser = isArray(this.currentUser) ? this.currentUser[0].attributes.CurrentUser : this.currentUser.attributes.CurrentUser;
      post.containerId = this.containerId;
      post.containerType = this.containerType;

      post.links = {};
      post.docIds = [];
      post.docMasterCollection = [];
      post.objIds = [];
      post.message = this.commentForm.controls.message.value;
      post.subject = this.commentForm.controls.subject.value;
      post.topicId = this.topicId;
      post.topicName = this.topicName;
      post.topicUser = this.topicUser;
      post.parentId = this.parentId;

var filesToUpload;// = this.dataService.getFileData();
      this.dataService.currentFile.subscribe(files => filesToUpload = files);
      if (filesToUpload && filesToUpload.length > 0) {
        var fileList: attachment[] = [];
        filesToUpload.forEach(element => {
          //var item = element.fileName + ":" + element.file;
          var item = new attachment();
          item.fileData = element.fileData;
          item.fileName = element.fileName;
          item.mimeType = element.mimeType;

          fileList.push(item);
        });
        post.attachments = fileList;
        this.dataService.setFileData = null;
        this.dataService.changeFileData(null);
      }
```

The problem that I am facing is when I add any document to the discussion and then in the list, it is showing the previously added document also and when submitting the post it is taking the previously added document + latest added document and I want to add only the current attachment not the previous one that already added to the last discussion successfully.

the above things I am doing in ngOnit() also and after the successful addition of the discussion, I cleared the documentalist still I am getting the same error.

Can anyone help me in this I am not able to identify what the problem is?

I am not able to share the complete code but if you want please let me know what are things that I need to share

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: can u add some code

Comment: @ShashankVivek please check the edited post.

Comment: try emptying  "var item" before assigning